# How can i filter the elements from a list that contains a div with specific text by clicking on a checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I 'm building a search function which is filtering the listed items by their names everytime a user is start typing into an input field and at the same time it counts the number of displayed items/results.

I added also a checkbox to allow users to filter the results by specific tags. In my current example there is a div with the class "open-or-close-tag". What i want is every time someone click on that checkbox, to hide all the elements that their "open-or-close-tag" divs contains the word "CLOSE" and still keep the counting number of the filtered items/results working right.

Here is my code:

```js
var langMap = {}
$('#count').text($('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length);
$('#search-stores-box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 var filteredWord = getLatinWord(valThis);
 if(filteredWord == ""){
  $('.storesList .store-block').show();
  $('.storesList .store-block').removeClass('hidden-store');    
 } else {
  $('.storesList .store-block').each(function(){
      $('.storesList .store-block').addClass('hidden-store'); 
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   text = getLatinWord(text);
   (text.indexOf(filteredWord) > -1 ) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });
 }
    var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length;
    $('#count').text(count);
});
function getLatinWord(word){
    return word.split('').map(function(character){
     if (langMap[character]) {
         return langMap[character];
     }
     return character;
 }).join('');
}

/* HERE IS THE EDITED CODE - NOW IT WORKS FINE */
$('#stores-open-now').on('click', function() {
if($('#stores-open-now').is(":checked")){
 $('.store-block').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('.open-or-close-tag').text() === "CLOSE"){
   $(this).hide();
  }else{
   $(this).show();
  }
 })
}else{
 $('.store-block').show();
}
var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length;
    $('#count').text(count);
});
```

```css
.results-box {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.search-area {margin-bottom:10px;}

.storesList {margin-top:20px;}
#count {display:inline-block;}

.store-block {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.open-or-close-tag {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:5px;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:blue;
}

.right{float:right;}
.left{float:left;}

.checkbox-lab {font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results-box">Number of stores:
<div id="count"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-area">
<input placeholder="Type a store name..." id="search-stores-box" type="text" />
</div> 



<div class="checkboxes-area">
<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>OPEN STORES</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="stores-open-now">

</label>
</div>


<div class="storesList">

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
</div>

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
</div>

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
</div>



</div>
```

Here's also a **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/pk670h9w/)**

Comment: I am not too familiar with jQuery but I can maybe help you with algorithm. What you can do is whenever someone clicks on the checkbox, select all the pertinent items, count them and store the value somewhere (say a global variable "reduce"). Then when you are updating the count, just subtract the reduce. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I ll give it a try.

Comment: *"still keep the counting number of the filtered items/results working right"* - so should the count (that's currently 3) change to 1 (in this instance) when the 'open stores' is clicked, or do you still want it to display the total number (3)?

Comment: @RachelGallen yep it should display 1 (in the current example) but i fixed that by myself. Thank you.

Comment: @Designer it may be helpful to future users if you posted the modified line of code (perhaps as a comment or a commented line in the answer)... . just a suggestion..

Comment: @RachelGallen check my snippet above. Based on the answer of Marco Messina i edited the code and added the counting fix. Thank you.

Comment: @Designer good stuff. Always good to see progress! :)

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you. Still learning. Everyday for me something new :)

Comment: @Designer I'm still learning too.. I'm afraid of the day I stop learning! .. love it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a change in the script. can you take a look to see if this was what you wanted?

```js
var langMap = {}
$('#count').text($('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length);
$('#search-stores-box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 var filteredWord = getLatinWord(valThis);
 if(filteredWord == ""){
  $('.storesList .store-block').show();
  $('.storesList .store-block').removeClass('hidden-store');    
 } else {
  $('.storesList .store-block').each(function(){
      $('.storesList .store-block').addClass('hidden-store'); 
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   text = getLatinWord(text);
   (text.indexOf(filteredWord) > -1 ) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });
 }
    var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length;
    $('#count').text(count);
});
function getLatinWord(word){
    return word.split('').map(function(character){
     if (langMap[character]) {
         return langMap[character];
     }
     return character;
 }).join('');
}

/* HERE IS WHAT I TRIED & DIDN'T WORK */
$('#stores-open-now').on('click', function() {
if($('#stores-open-now').is(":checked")){
 $('.store-block').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('.open-or-close-tag').text() === "CLOSE"){
   $(this).hide();
  }else{
   $(this).show();
  }
 })
}else{
 $('.store-block').show();
}
});
```

```css
.results-box {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.search-area {margin-bottom:10px;}

.storesList {margin-top:20px;}
#count {display:inline-block;}

.store-block {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.open-or-close-tag {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:5px;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:blue;
}

.right{float:right;}
.left{float:left;}

.checkbox-lab {font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results-box">Number of stores:
<div id="count"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-area">
<input placeholder="Type a store name..." id="search-stores-box" type="text" />
</div> 



<div class="checkboxes-area">
<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>OPEN STORES</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="stores-open-now">

</label>
</div>


<div class="storesList">

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
</div>

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
</div>

<div class="store-block">
<div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
<div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
</div>



</div>
```